# ASP.NET MVC Validation Architecture for DB Validated values

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

lets say i have a class like so

```
public class Blog{
  [Key]
  public int ID{get;set;}

  //these can only be tags that are in the tags db table
  IEnumerable<string> Tags{get;set;}

  //validation pseudocode to illustrate issue
  public bool IsValid() {

    //this is my issue-- how do i get my db context/repository 
    //into my validation logic for this class? i need it
    var goodTags=db.Tags.Select(i=>i.Name);

    //if this tag isn't a "goodTag", then this shouldnt validate
    Tags.ForEach(i=> {

       if(!goodTags.Contains(i))
          return false;
    });
 }
 }
```

How do i validate that the string contained in Tags are in the tags db table without putting data access logic in the model? I am using MVC3. How have you done it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the IInvalidatableObject for self validation as follows:

```
public Class Blog : IValidatableObject
{
      [Key]
      public int Id {get; set;}

      public ICollection<string> Tags {get; set;}


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(!Tags.Contains("testString"))
        {
              yield return new ValidationResult("Not a valid tag.", new [] {"Tags"});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added more code to show the real issue--getting the data context into the model for IValidateableObject. Thanks a ton for answering, very appreciated.

Comment: What is your repository architecture? Entity?